# Is Redis SET command blocking other SET commands until it finish?

Tags: redis

Since Redis is single threaded it shouldn't allow any other `SET` commands to start until initial one finishes, right?

In my application each `SET` saves between 1 and 300 MB of data, so it would be a bottleneck probably (network overhead etc)

Comment: I store files in Redis, other application component receives file from the user and uploads it over internal network to the Redis instance. I've just performed a test and in version 4 of the server it works just fine when I connect with 2 redis-cli, upload a large, time consuming file in first and other small file in second. While first one is still processing, I've successfully uploaded second one, performed "GET" on it (first SET was still unfinished).

Comment: no one answer this. I'm curious about this too..